# Replacement for saxon:if and saxon:before functions in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

Is there any replacement for [saxon:if](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.2/extensions.html#if) 
and [saxon:before](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/extensions.html#before) functions in XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0?

I have code like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="stop"
  select="(following-sibling::h:h1|following-sibling::h:h2)[1]" />

<xsl:variable name="between"
  select="saxon:if($stop,
                   saxon:before(following-sibling::*, $stop),
                   following-sibling::*)" />
```

Idea is that `between` variable should contain all elements between current node and next `h1` or `h2` element (stored in `stop` variable), or all remaining elements, if there is no next `h1` or `h2`.

I'd like to use this code in new XSLT 2.0 template, and I am looking for replacement for `saxon:if` and `saxon:before`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
<xsl:variable 
     name="stop"
     select="(following-sibling::h:h1|following-sibling::h:h2)[1]" />

<xsl:variable name="between">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$stop">
            <xsl:sequence select="following-sibling::*[. &lt;&lt; $stop]" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="following-sibling::*" />
         </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

It uses [`<xsl:sequence>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-sequence) and [`<<` operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-node-before) (encoded as `&lt;&lt;`), from XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0.

It's not as short as original version, but it doesn't use saxon extensions anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`saxon.if(A, B, C)` is now equivalent to `if (A) then B else C` in XPath 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You also could use just one expression in XSLT/XPath 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="p[position()=(1,3,4)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*
                                [not(self::h2|self::h1)]
                                [not(. >>
                                     current()
                                        /following-sibling::*
                                            [self::h2|self::h1][1])]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<html>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>3</p>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<p>2</p><p>5</p>
```